# Householder transformation example

Tags: matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

The question asks to construct a Householder matrix **H** that maps the vector **x** = (4,0,3) onto the vector **y** = (5,0,0), by checking first that $|x| = |y|$ and then designing a unit vector **w** such that $$H(w) := I - \frac{2ww^*}{w^*w}$$

I understand that obviously $$|x| = \sqrt{16 + 9} = \sqrt{25} = 5 = \sqrt{25} = |y|$$ and know that $w^* = w^T$ as well as a unit vector **w** means $|w| = 1$. But i'm struggling to find where to start to find **w**.

Comment: You have done a mistake on the bottom right coefficient; instead of $4/9$, it should be $-4/5$. Besides, I dont understand your computation because $w=x-y$ should be $(4,0,3)^T-(5,0,0)^T=(-1,0,3)^T$ (I put a transpose $T$ for indicating that it is a column vector). Moreover the norm of $w$ should be $\sqrt{(-1)^2+0^2+3^2}=\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. I must've mixed numbers from another example I was trying to understand. If you post as an answer I can vote it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested in the solution:

I've used $$v = x - y = \frac{(-1,0,3)^T}{\sqrt(10)}$$ where I can then find $w = \frac{v}{|v|}$. This gives me the solution of $$H(w) :=\begin{bmatrix}4/5 & 0 & 3/5\\0 & 1 & 0\\3/5 & 0 & -4/5\end{bmatrix}$$ which maps **x** = (4,0,3) onto **y** = (5,0,0).

Confirmed by using H(w)**x** = **y**